# How is the AspectJ cflow pointcut implemented?

Tags: java, aspectj, control-flow

How does AspectJ check if the execution is happening in the control flow of, say, a method?
It could be a very useful insight, to be able to implement the functionality on its own, outside of an AspectJ project.

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out by myself :-) 
AspectJ uses a ThreadLocal variable to keep track of the control flow. 
Source: AspectJ's own [FAQ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/faq.php#q%3aruntimeMemory)